# jQuery onclick function clean up

Tags: jquery, hide

the piece of code shown below is working fine, except it looks a bit amateuristic to my opinion (made it myself :P ). I'm sure this can be much cleaner. So my question is how to combine those 'hides'? Any other suggestions?

```
$('.login_inputbox').removeClass("register_inputbox_error login_inputbox_error").removeClass("register_inputbox_ok login_inputbox_ok");
validator.resetForm();
$(".btn-slide_login").removeClass("active_login");
$(".btn-slide_all").removeClass("active_all");
$('#fancybox-wrap').hide();
$('#fancybox-overlay').hide();
$('#panel_login').hide();
$('#panel_all').hide();
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: what's the relationship between your question and "onclick function"?

Comment: because this piece of code is placed inside a onclick function. If you know a better title you are free to update :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To combine the `.hide()` statements you'd need a selector that applies to all four elements. You could do this:

```
$('#fancybox-wrap,#fancybox-overlay,#panel_login,#panel_all').hide();
```

Or you could give those elements a common class:

```
$('.someClass').hide();
```

Note also that your first line can be simplified by combining the `.removeClass()` calls:

```
$('.login_inputbox').removeClass("register_inputbox_error login_inputbox_error register_inputbox_ok login_inputbox_ok");
```

Answer (score 5):

You can uss `removeClass` once as follows

```
$('.login_inputbox').removeClass("register_inputbox_error login_inputbox_error register_inputbox_ok login_inputbox_ok");
```

instead of using it twice as follows

```
$('.login_inputbox').removeClass("register_inputbox_error login_inputbox_error").removeClass("register_inputbox_ok login_inputbox_ok");
```

and also

```
$('#fancybox-wrap, #fancybox-overlay, #panel_login, #panel_all').hide();
```

instead of

```
$('#fancybox-wrap').hide();
$('#fancybox-overlay').hide();
$('#panel_login').hide();
$('#panel_all').hide();
```

Comment: tnx to you too for the lesson! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can comma separate selectors. ex:

```
$('#fancybox-wrap, #fancybox-overlay, #panel_login, #panel_all').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you give `#fancybox-wrap` and friends a class in common, call it `new-class`, you could do:

```
$('.newclass').hide();
```

and get all four at once.